# Firefox bouncy effect bug

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser

I have made small fiddle in here http://jsfiddle.net/DV6JA/4/

I don't understand firefox. Long time age IE was a problematic browser but right now there is many bugs in firefox.

Why in this example, <.txt> element jump on bottom. I try to change font size, but it sometimes help and sometimes doesn't. 
When i put some sorter text in <.cnt> it sometimes doesn't jump. So where is problem for firefox?

HTML:

```
<li class='tag_glass'>
     <a>
        <p class='cnt'>999+</p>
        <p class='txt'>some txt in here</p>
     </a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
li a{
  display:inline-block;
}

.txt{
    float:left;
 }
.cnt{
  font-size:9px;
  float:left;
}
```

JS:

```
$('li a').mouseenter(function(){

    $(this).effect( "bounce",{times:3,distance:10},1000 );

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can wrap the `a` tag with a div and apply the bounce effect on this div.
I also added a width to the div and the p elements, I don't know if you can accept reducing their widths but take a look at it.

Here's the updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DV6JA/15/)**

Hope it helps...

Comment: but i don't want to clear left, i want .txt next to .cnt - and even this with long words in .txt element will jump in FF.

Comment: I edited the answer and the fiddle .. hope you like it

Comment: no ... in my example it doesn't work. When i change font size - it jump to bottom.

Comment: ok it works now ... i found other "solution" and add +1 in width by JS when element is bouncing. Firefox has some problem with that :)